# numpy array getting out columns according to a list returns rows wrapped in extra array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix (2d numpy array) and I want to create a new 2d array composed of a subset of columns from the original matrix. What I tried is this:

`X[:, columnList]` and `columnList = [1, 3 ,5]` (column list is an example). But what happened is that the result of this was a 2d array where every row was wrapped in another array.

Example:

```
X = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 2.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 51.0, 221.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 91.0, 22.0], [13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 41.0, 82.0], [16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 11.0, 32.0], [19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 12.0, 23.0], [22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 6.0, 12.0], [25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 4.0, 8.0]])


featureList = [1, 3]
dataMat = X[:, [featureIndexList]]
```

Output of dataMat:

```
array([[[  2.,   1.]],

   [[  5.,   1.]],

   [[  8.,  51.]],

   [[ 11.,  91.]],

   [[ 14.,  41.]],

   [[ 17.,  11.]],

   [[ 20.,  12.]],

   [[ 23.,   6.]],

   [[ 26.,   4.]]])
```

What I want:

```
array([[  2.,   1.],

   [  5.,   1.],

   [  8.,  51.],

   [ 11.,  91.],

   [ 14.,  41.],

   [ 17.,  11.],

   [ 20.,  12.],

   [ 23.,   6.],

   [ 26.,   4.]])
```

Any ideas how to do this easily?

Comment: Lose the brackets : `X[:, featureList]`.

Comment: ah of course. thanks

Comment: or just squeeze out the extra dimension x = x.squeeze()